# get xml node by order

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

i have the xml file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Config>
  <MetadataFormConfig FieldInternalName="Test">
         <Tabs>
             <Tab Title="A to C" Order="1">
                 <ShowParentTerm>A</ShowParentTerm>
                 <ShowParentTerm>B</ShowParentTerm>
                 <ShowParentTerm>C1</ShowParentTerm>

             </Tab>
             <Tab Title="D to E" Order="2">
                 <ShowParentTerm>D</ShowParentTerm>
                 <ShowParentTerm>E</ShowParentTerm>
      </Tab>

    </Tabs>
  </MetadataFormConfig>
</Config>
```

i want to get tab element by order. if i changed tab Title="A to c" order to 2 then i want to get the node "D to E" first then "A to C"

can any one help me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"test.xml");
var tabs = doc.Descendants("Tab")
              .OrderBy(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Attribute("Order").Value))
              .ToList();
```

This will select a list of tab elements ordered by the value of the `Order` attribute.

Comment: i get this error when used your code: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to add  `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Xml.Linq;` to your program

Comment: ya got it. but i want to first get MetadataFormConfig node by "FieldInternalName" and then get tab by order. can u please suggest me how can i do it?

Comment: To get the `FieldInternalName` value you could do `var metadata = doc.Descendants("MetadataFormConfig").First().Attribute("FieldInternalName").Value;` - not sure if this answers your question.